# How to store name of dynamic checkbox in an String array

Tags: c#, arrays

How can store name of dynamically created checkbox in a String array when I don't know how many checkbox will user select at runtime.
Say I have 10 dynamic checkboxes and out of 10 user select 6 checkboxes randomly now how can get the name of those selected checkboxes and store them in a String array.

I know how to use event handler on dynamic check box but confused how to declare Straing array when I don't know what will be be size of an array.

Here what I have done till now -

```
    private void CheckBoxCheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox c = (CheckBox)sender;
        //Label myLabel;
        String str = null;
        if (c.Checked == true)
        {
            str = c.Text;
            gpBox[gpcount] = new GroupBox();
            gpBox[gpcount].Name = "gpBox" + Convert.ToString(count);
            gpBox[gpcount].Text = str;
            gpBox[gpcount].Location = new Point(5, gpposition);
            gpBox[gpcount].AutoSize = true;
            this.Controls.Add(gpBox[gpcount]);

            aCommand3 = new OleDbCommand("select * from batch_tbl where batch_branch LIKE '" + str + "'", main_connection);
            aAdapter3 = new OleDbDataAdapter(aCommand3);
            ds3 = new DataSet();
            aAdapter3.Fill(ds3, "app_info");
            ds3.Tables[0].Constraints.Add("pk_bno", ds3.Tables[0].Columns[0], true);
            int batch_count = ds3.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
            batchCheckBox = new CheckBox[batch_count];
            //filling the groupbox with batch code by generating dynamic checkboxes
            for (int j=0; j < batch_count; ++j)
            {
                batchCheckBox[j] = new CheckBox();
                batchCheckBox[j].Name = "batch" + Convert.ToString(k);
                batchCheckBox[j].Text = ds3.Tables[0].Rows[j][1].ToString();
                Console.WriteLine(batchCheckBox[j].Text);
                batchCheckBox[j].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(104 * position, 30);
                gpBox[gpcount].Controls.Add(batchCheckBox[j]);
                batchCheckBox[j].CheckStateChanged += new System.EventHandler(BatchBoxCheckedChanged);
                position++;
                count++;
                Console.WriteLine(batchCheckBox[j].Name);
                k++;
            }
            position = 1;
            gpposition += 100;
        }
        else
        {
            count--;
            this.Controls.RemoveByKey("lbl" + c.Name);
            this.Update();
        }
    }
    int total_batch = 1;
    string[] batchname;
    private void BatchBoxCheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox batchBox = (CheckBox)sender;
        //Here I want to store name of checkbox in array
        if (batchBox.Checked == true)
        {
            batchname = new String[total_batch];
            total_batch++;

        }
        else
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: if you just want to save name of checkboxes in array. then instead of array, use `List<string> names=new List<string>()`

Comment: @ Sachine thank you gor guidance please give me some highlights on so I can use list, as I am new for list. Furthur I have to pass these names to another form

Comment: @user2241865 a list is basacly an array that can dynamically ajust in size (capacity). It is easier to work with in most senarios :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
    //Gets all checkbox's on the form
    List<CheckBox> chks = Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().ToList();

    //take only those who is checked, and select only their name property
    List<string> names = chks.Where(c => c.Checked).Select(c => c.Name).ToList();
```

**UPDATE**

For testing you could print a list of the selected names:

```
string txt = "";
foreach(string name in names)
{
   txt += name+" \n\r";
}
MessageBox.Show(txt);
```

Comment: @ Jens I tried your code snippet but show error- System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox does not contain a definition for IsChecked

Comment: @user2241865 sorry. try using `c.Checked` instead of `c.IsChecked`. I have updated my answer

Comment: @ Jens I already tried that also and found this error -               Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: @user2241865 ooh, i missed a `.ToList()` at the end - i have updated my answer

Comment: @ Jens Please tell me where I am wrong I am not able to see the name of selected checkbox

Comment: @user2241865 not sure what you mean. but I have updated my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everbody

```
}
        list = new List<string>();
    }

    private void BatchBoxCheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox batchBox = (CheckBox)sender;
        //Here I want to store name of checkbox in array

        if (batchBox.Checked == true)
        {
            list.Add(batchBox.Text);  
        }
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach(string prime in list) // Loop through List with foreach
        {
            Console.WriteLine(prime);
        }
    }
```

This is Done